# Product cost, product price, profit margin: do all of those belong on the database?

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

I'm trying to model a database of a Point of Sale type of system and wonder which - if any - of 3 values should be calculated at runtime based on the other 2 as opposed to saved as a static value in the products table.

My concern is that because the user will be able to list and search (filter) products by any of those values, that calculating anyone of those at response time could either hinder performance of make search features complicated.

Comment: so what exactly your question is about?

Comment: If I should/need to have all of them as table rows of if any of them should not be  in database and instead be dynamically calculated at query time

Comment: There are no absolutes - pick the one that solves your problem better *for you*.

Comment: Maybe I should have added a disclaimer that I'm learning backend development, hence the question. It's hard for me at this level of knowledge to figure out the best option. If both options are valid, I'm looking for at least learning about the tradeoffs and consequences of each strategy

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for at least learning about the tradeoffs and consequences of each strategy

It seems that you know the tradeoffs.  You are trading the additional storage and possible data integrity issues for better performance.  There's not a "right" answer, but I would start with calculating it on the fly and then try to improve the performance *if that is a measurable bottleneck*. Until you can measure that it's a problem you are just guessing.  The risk of having bad data (e.g. not recalculating the margin if one of the components changes) is real, however.

Plus there are other things to consider - a product can have *different* prices (discounts, custom contracted prices, etc.) and costs, so that may change your data strategy even further.

Comment: discounts, etc are accounted for in specific tables, such as the 'sales' table. I thing you forgot to mention which 2 should I keep?

Comment: Becasue there's not a "right" answer.  There are trade-offs, and you seem to know what they are.  My opinion (for what it's worth) is to not store ANY calculated values until absolutely necessary.  Storing calculated values increases the risk that the components that resulted in the calculated value change but the calculated value does not, resulting in a data integrity problem.

Comment: So the columns you want to keep depend on what is calculated - do you have a fixed margin and calculate the price from the margin and the cost?  Or do you have a set price and calculate the margin?

Answer (score 0):

In an operational (transactional database):

Cost: yes
Price: yes
Profit: no

In an analytic database (data warehouse): store all three

Comment: Thanks, but what is the reasoning?